# Interrupting ModelBuilder between two processes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

I am using a model builder to create a tool that uses a DEM to create contour lines. Then I want to select, on screen, one of the contour lines to use it as an input parameter for the clip tool to clip the DEM. Is it possible to interrupt the model builder tool in run time so the user can select a specific contour lines and then the tool continues to the next step (clipping).

Comment: I'm not aware of a tool that can manage this manipulation; I guess your options are: 1. create 2 distinct tools; 2. Use selection within the model base and a-priori parameters that user can define; 3. code the break() / pause() in the code using python. Unfortunately I can't help with option #3. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a ModelBuilder model can only be run from start to finish without interruption.

Consequently, as commented by @dof1985, I think your only option is to create two models/tools that you run before and after your user operation.

You could orchestrate them using a Python AddIn.